# textarea some characters goes outside the container

Tags: javascript, css, textarea, font-face

I'm facing the following issue, I have an editable textarea resizable with dynamic font sizing.

I should also support text alignment (left / center / right) and text transform(uppercase / lowercase). My issue is that for some character in some fonts the text is partly rendered outside the textarea (text alignment right) like on the image below

[image]

The problem is that since the font-size size is dynamic and can be really big (up to 300px) adding some padding to fully display the text could lead in a really small editable area.
Did someone faced the same problem or have an idea of how this problem can be faced?

Comment: I hope you will get scroll bars if the font is much bigger. check this http://jsfiddle.net/s74cprb7/

Comment: My textarea has overflow:hidden because I resize the text to fit the container

Comment: link to fiddle showing the issue http://jsfiddle.net/oiledCode/s74cprb7/1/